# Change component filename

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to change the file name when generating a component used for cli angular.

For example, I need a component with the name my-component-name.page.(htlm,scss,ts). I'm using the --type option but the error always appears:

Error: Unknown argument: type.

[image]

Comment: What version of the CLI are you using?

Comment: 14.0.6, i have another project with 13.1.4 and work's perfect.

Comment: If you run `ng v` does it actually show your project CLI as 14, or are you just looking at your package.json version?

Comment: i run ng v; response: Angular CLI: 14.0.6

Comment: I run the command ng g c --help, and in the list of options it effectively doesn't have the --type flag. It was probably removed from version 13 to 14;